# Multiple Test Methods in TestClass

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0

Hi I am curious about how units tests work in Visual Studio default Testing package. I have three test methods marked with TestMethod attribute ina  class marked with TestClass attribute.

Now when I run all tests does:
1. Runtime create a new instance of class for each test method?
2. Is each method run parallel in a thread?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your questions:

1. A separate `TestClass` instance is created for each of the contained `TestMethod`s.
2. Each test is potentially executed on its own thread, allowing the tests to be run in parallel.

This information can be found in [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nnaderi/archive/2007/02/01/mstest-vs-nunit-frameworks.aspx):

> In MSTest, each test is instantiated on a separate thread, this results the runs being interleaved.

Additionally, this is why the `ClassInitialize` method is static: since a `TestClass` instance isn't shared between tests, the only way tests can share state with each other is via static variables.